# Why am I getting two app icon after install app.? Unity3D

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob, android-manifest

I am getting two app icon after installing my unity game app. I use google official plugins for ads and I put everything that he say's in Androidmanifest.xml file. Below is my code anyone can check and help me. thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
This Google Mobile Ads plugin library manifest will get merged with your
application's manifest, adding the necessary activity and permissions
required for displaying ads.
-->

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.google.unity.ads"
    android:versionName="1.0"
    android:versionCode="1">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" />

  <application>
       <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
                android:value="[App_ID]"/>

      <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AD_MANAGER_APP"
                android:value="true"/>
      <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity"
           android:label="@string/app_name">
           <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
           <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
           <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik"
               android:value="true" />
    </activity>

  </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: have you changed the package name by chance?

Comment: I didn't try, suggest what can I put there.? and will that work?. because I think, I have problem in my code  related to activity.

Comment: no u dont want to. usually the package name controls the app name which would control there being more than one app.

Comment: okk i understand, I will try this.

Comment: Did you try to remove it(/them) from the device and deploy again?

Comment: Now it's not working. I tried that, I remove <Intent-filter> and it work, but still I am not getting my admob banner ads.